# Google BigQuery date string to timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to Google BigQuery. I have a date in this format Oct 7, 2019, 11:28:26 AM GMT+2 and would like to convert date into 2019-10-07, 11:28:26 AM GMT+2.

Answer (score 0):

Partital answer, this seems to do the job:

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP(
  '%b %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S %p GMT%z'
  , 'Oct 7, 2019, 11:28:26 AM GMT+02')
# 2019-10-07 09:28:26 UTC
```

However, I only got it to work if I express the timezone as `GMT+02`. `GMT+2` fails, and maybe someone else can help us get this one correctly parsed.

Then if you want to format the date as required:

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP(
  '%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S %p GMT%z'
  , x
  , '+2')
FROM (
  SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP(
     '%b %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S %p GMT%z'
     , 'Oct 7, 2019, 11:28:26 AM GMT+02'
  ) x
)
# 2019-10-07, 11:28:26 AM GMT+0200
```

Note that the original timezone "2" is lost when ingested into a timestamp.

Comment: Thank you very much Felipe. This is for single date. How i can change the same format date in a table and get all list of dates as a result? For example if my dates are in the column "day".

Comment: replace ` 'Oct 7, 2019, 11:28:26 AM GMT+02'` with `day` and add a `FROM` to get your table

Comment: I tried it says failed to parse input String 'Day'. Is there any other format that i can change date Oct 7, 2019, 11:28:26 AM GMT+02?